# Multiply textbox values with like IDs

Tags: jquery, math

I have a series of textboxes that I need to multiply the values and display the result in a corrsponding span. The ID values all start with similar values, so I am trying to come up with an elegant solution to perform this function.

Here is some sample code:

```
<tr><td><input type="text" name="addsys-lru-1"/></td><td><input type="number" name="addsys-lbs-1"/></td><td><input type="number" name="addsys-arm-1"/></td><td><span id="addsys-moment-1"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="addsys-lru-2"/></td><td><input type="number" name="addsys-lbs-2"/></td><td><input type="number" name="addsys-arm-2"/></td><td><span id="addsys-moment-2"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="addsys-lru-3"/></td><td><input type="number" name="addsys-lbs-3"/></td><td><input type="number" name="addsys-arm-3"/></td><td><span id="addsys-moment-3"></span></td></tr>
```

I need to multiply the value in addsys-lbs-n with the value in addsys-arm-n and display in the associated addsys-moment-n. So I am basically looking for an elegant solution for the following code:

```
$('#addsys-arm-1').focusout(function(){
   var weight = $('#addsys-lbs-1').val();
   var arm = $('#addsys-arm-1').val();
   var sum = weight * arm;
   $('#addsys-moment-1').html(sum);
});
```

Wherein each set of addsys-lbs and addsys-arm values will display in the addsys-moment span.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not give them a class? Then you can find the element with that class in the same row, and multiply them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes for all the similar elements. Then you can find the Weight field in the same row as the the Arm field by searching for the class.

```js
$('.addsys-arm').focusout(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var weight = row.find('.addsys-lbs').val();
  var arm = $(this).val();
  var sum = weight * arm;
  row.find('.addsys-moment').text(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><th>LRU</th><th>Weight</th><th>Arm</th><th>Moment</th></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class="addsys-lru" name="addsys-lru-1"/></td><td><input type="number" class="addsys-lbs" name="addsys-lbs-1"/></td><td><input type="number" class="addsys-arm" name="addsys-arm-1"/></td><td><span class="addsys-moment" id="addsys-moment-1"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class="addsys-lru" name="addsys-lru-2"/></td><td><input type="number" class="addsys-lbs" name="addsys-lbs-2"/></td><td><input type="number" class="addsys-arm" name="addsys-arm-2"/></td><td><span class="addsys-moment" id="addsys-moment-2"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class="addsys-lru" name="addsys-lru-3"/></td><td><input type="number" class="addsys-lbs" name="addsys-lbs-3"/></td><td><input type="number" class="addsys-arm" name="addsys-arm-3"/></td><td><span class="addsys-moment" id="addsys-moment-3"></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Geez. I don't know why I didn't think about that. Thanks for the solution.